# constructing URL with struts 2 param tag if param vaue is null/empty?

Tags: java, struts2

I'm making below url through Struts 2 tag. The problem is if there is no attribute 'cust_key' in request, url does not append **?custKey_key=** to the url.

```
 var custUrl= '<s:url  namespace="/customer" action="view-customer" method="viewCustomer" escapeAmp="false"/> <s:param name="custKey_key" value="#request['cust_key']" /> </s:url>';
```

Is there a attribute in `s:param` tag where specified param  is always appended even if value is empty or `null`?

Comment: <s:url /> your first tag is self-closed?

Comment: Just for curiosity, why do need to pass empty attribute to the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [JavaDocs](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.1.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/components/URL.html) of this custom tag (please see inherited `addParameter` method):

> ... If the provided value is null any existing parameter with the given
>   key name is removed...

So you need to pass some value, you could try at least empty string.